# In pytest, is there a way to mock an already imported variable without having to patch for every single test?

Tags: python, pytest

So to be specific, we're using SqlAlchemy and session, and we use define it only once at say, at `utils/sessions.py`. like following :

```
#utils/sessions.py

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

session = scoped_session (sessionmaker(
 ....
))
```

and we use this on our actual repository layer, for example :

```
#app/user/users.py
from utils.sessions import session

class UserRepo :
  def get_user(self,id) :
    return session.query(User).filter(User.id=id)
```

Now I'm trying to perform some sort of unit/integration test, and I need to mock the `session` variable that came from `utils.sessions` in practically everywhere within the test (hence I would like to use an autouse fixture mocking `util.sessions.session`).

so far, the only thing that seemed to be worked was to patch `app.user.users.session` within the test code itself , While what i want is to basically mock every single occurance of `session` in different tests too. like, if i want to test `app/articles` , I wouldn't want to repeatedly type `with patch('apps.articles.article.session'` unnecessarily.

so ideally, I would like to have something like this and expect all my occurance of `session` imported in individual repos to work properly :

```
# tests/conftest.py

def mocked_session() :
 return scoped_session("my_new_parameters_for_test_purpose_only")

@pytest.fixture(autouse=true)
def mock_all_sessions():
 with patch("utils.sessions.session", mocked_session) as s :
  yield s
```

but this didn't work for me. (It's strange for me because patching `socket.socket` successfully blocks networking attempt.)

it would be nice if there was a way to mock `utils.sessions.session` instead of having to manually patch `apps/{all apps i have}/{all .py files}.session/`.

Is there a way to do this? if not, would there be an alternative to having to manually write down the module path for every single test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the unittest documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

The main issue is that when you patch, you are only patching the name a variable in the context of a module. When `users.py` does `from utils.sessions import session` it creates its own reference to session. i.e. there are two variable names which point to the same object.

```
utils.sessions.session = <your session object>
app.user.users.session = <your session object>
```

When you patch just `utils.sessions.session` you are only replacing the contents of the name in that module. e.g.

```
utils.sessions.session = <the patched mock object>
app.user.users.session = <your session object>
```

If you instead do the import as `from utils import sessions` then you would reference the object as `sessions.session`, which means when you patch the value on the `sessions` module, it will find the correct override to the patched value at runtime.

IMO This becomes awkward because it imposes a certain style of performing imports on you, when both should be technically valid. An easier pattern might be to create a proxy method inside of `sessions.py` that will put a barrier in between importers of the module and accessing the session object. That would look like this:

```
_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(...))

def session():
    return _session
```

used like:

```
from utils.sessions import session

class UserRepo:
  def get_user(self,id):
    return session().query(User).filter(User.id=id)
```

Now when you go to patch, you only have to patch `utils.sessions._session`, and it doesn't matter how you do the import. The reference to the function `session()` remains unchanged, but the object it would return is changed for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you mock `session` only in one namespace, i.e. `utils.sessions.__dict__`, but the name "session" exists in many other namespaces e.g. `apps.articles.article.__dict__`.

There is a low-tech solution possible by simply changing import statements - instead of

```
from utils.sessions import session
```

You could use

```
from utils import sessions
```

Then you only need to mock in the one namespace (where the name is looked up) as you're already doing. The caveat is that all those submodules now need to use `sessions.session` instead of just `session`, so that they are all looking in the same namespace where you're applying the patch.